# Make buttons remain pressed in PySImpleGUI

Tags: python, user-interface, button, pysimplegui

I have these 3 buttons configured, and they are basically 3 options from which you can only have 1 active at a time. I'm trying to have the following behavior: when one is clicked, it should remain clicked until another one is clicked, is this even possible?

```
    # Settings Buttons layout
    settingsButtonsLine = [
        [psg.Button("CITY ROAD", size=(20, 7), button_color='Gray', font=mainFont),
         psg.Button("NORMAL ROAD", size=(20, 7), button_color='Gray', font=mainFont),
         psg.Button("HIGHWAY", size=(20, 7), button_color='Gray', font=mainFont)]
    ]
```

[image]

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72344874/is-there-a-way-to-visually-hold-a-button-after-its-been-pressed-in-pysimlegui/72345576#72345576

Comment: oh, didn't see that, thanks

Comment: There's also a PySimpleGUI Demo Program - Demo_Radio_Buttons_Simulated.py that uses the color of a button to perform that kind of operation you're looking for.